# Showing a sequence is a Cauchy sequence in $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $A \in \operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$ with $\| A \| < 1$. Show that $( \sum_{0 \leq k \leq l} A^k )_{l \in \Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$, and conclude that the following element is well-defined in the complete space $\operatorname{End}(\Bbb R^n)$:
>   $$\sum_{k \in \Bbb N_0} A^k := \lim_{l \to \infty} \sum_{0 \leq k \leq l} A^k$$

This is part (ii) of Exercise 2.3 in Duistermaat's Multidimensional Real Analysis, volume 1. I have attempted a few venues of attack:

My attempt is noting that $$\left\| \sum_{0 \leq k \leq l} A^k \right\| \leq \sum_{0 \leq k \leq l} \| A \|^k,$$ and since on the right we have a geometric series it converges.

I'm not confident on this and rather clueless.

Comment: This is indeed a correct proof.

Comment: Well, it is not really a proof. You should really show that the sequence is Cauchy, which you have not done, but the basic idea is similar. In particular, you need to bound $\left\|  \sum_{0 \leq k \leq m} A^k -\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} A^k \right\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As copper.hat noted, to show that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy you need to estimate truncated partial sums: for every $\epsilon$ there is $N$ such that 
$$
\left\| \sum_{m \leq k \leq l} A^k \right\| \leq \epsilon ,\quad \text{whenever } \ l\ge m\ge N
$$
To get there, it is reasonable to use the known fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \|A\|^k$ converges. Indeed, since this series converges, its partial sums are Cauchy, and therefore  for every $\epsilon$ there is $N$ such that 
$$
 \sum_{m \leq k \leq l} \|A\|^k \leq \epsilon ,\quad \text{whenever } \ l\ge m\ge N
$$
Now the triangle inequality indeed finishes the proof.

By the way, you may note that this proof generalizes to an arbitrary series of operators $A_k$: if it converges absolutely (meaning $\sum \|A_k\|<\infty$), then it converges.